# Can a VST Plugin Access the Entire MIDI Track?

Tags: plugins, midi, vst

Is it possible to write a VST plugin that looks ahead to upcoming MIDI events, or ideally the entire MIDI track?

Comment: No. You can fake it a little by telling the host you have some latency, that will give you some extra microseconds worth of look-ahead data. VST 2.x does have an offline section with some functions, but I don't think anybody supports that. Offline processing would allow a plugin to process events non-real time (ideally faster than real time). [2c]

Comment: Thanks.  I need at least a couple of seconds look-ahead because I want to reshape note articulation based on upcoming events.  It looks like I'll have to find some other way to do it.  Max for Live can access the entire track but I was hoping for a more general solution.  Maybe I could have the user paste the entire midi track into the plugin.

Comment: @obiwanjacobi: WaveLab does support VstOfflineTask. It's pretty much the only thing that does. VST3 support for "offline" tasks is much more widespread (and uses a different api), but the name is pretty misleading in the latter case. They are much less "offline" than what VST2 provided. Can't shorten a wavefile for instance with VST3 "offline".